# We are conjoined twins. Can you guess us?

Tags: riddle

> We are conjoined twins
>
> We looks same but we aren’t
>
> We can mark you
>
> We can add style to you
>
> We can make you feel shy sometimes
>
> We can change our body colors
>
> We can reduce stress to you
>
> We can protect you
>
> We can make you  clear

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We are

> Eyeglasses, or more specifically, the lenses in the eyeglasses.

We are conjoined twins

> We are connected by the nose piece.

We looks same but we aren’t

> We are basically mirror images, and we may have different strengths.

We can mark you

> Glasses can help identify you, and can leave marks on your nose or the sides of your face, depending on the fit.

We can add style to you

> Glasses can make one look stylish.

We can make you fell shy sometimes

> Some people feel shy when they first get glasses, often due to fear of being teased.

We can change our body colors

> Some lenses are transition lenses, which can darken in the bright light, and clear when indoors or in shadows or other darkness.

We can reduce stress to you

> People get glasses because they have difficultly reading things, which can be stressful and cause headaches.

We can protect you

> Some types of glasses have protective lenses for sports, or other safety purposes, and in general, glasses can protect the eyes from debris, and most come with UV protection.

We can make you clear

> Wearing glasses can help you see clearly.

Comment: Looks like this has to be right. +1.

Comment: And *I* thought it was something with M$ Word...